# Binding meta-data to D3 parallel coordinates

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, data-binding, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to bind some meta-data to dimensions in the [parallel coordinates D3 implementation](https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/).

Currently, the only data which is bound to the parcoords comes from a simple .CSV with headers and polyline information. E.g. `mydata.csv`:

```
Header1     Header2     Header3     ...    Header_n
1.2         100         1997               ... 
1.8         120         1993
1.5         140         1991
```

Now I'd like to also use some meta-data (for example, a short sentence describing the axis content, the unit of the data, etc..) stored in a JSON object, by binding it to every existing dimension. E.g. `metadata`:

```
metadata = [
  {
    "sentence": "header1 represents foo",
    "unit": "[m]",
    "header": "header1",
  },
  {
    "sentence": "header2 represents bar",
    "unit": "[s]",
    "header": "header2",
  }
]
```

So far I've come up with the following workaround, but it has (at least) two shortfalls:

```
// Add metadata to visible dimensions
myElementd3 = d3.selectAll(".dimension");
myElementd3[0].forEach(function(d,i) {
      d["sentence"] = metadata[i]["sentence"];
      d["unit"] = metadata[i]["unit"];
});
```

- The metadata is not correctly matching the axes, because I'm not sure how to match the bound csv data with the elements in the metadata JSON object. Note that `header` in the JSON is the same as the header in the CSV, so I'm thinking a SQL-type join might be possible, though I'm unsure how.
- I can only bind the metadata to visible axes (because my csv contains over 20 dimensions, I use `.dimensions(header_disp)` to only display a sample of axes), so this should be repeated each time the displayed axes change

So summing up, I have the 2 following questions:

1. How could I match the correct metadata with its corresponding dimension (e.g. using something similar to SQL joins?)?
2. How could I select and apply this to all dimensions, even those which are not displayed?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: You have to provide **your** code.

Comment: Did you try structuring your metadata as an object? If `metadata = { header1: { sentence: ..., unit: ... }, header2: {...}` then you can look up the metadata based on its key, instead of array position.